# ggplot automate legend position in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if there is a way to automate legend positioning in ggplot.
I want to put my legend within the plot but do not want to specify the position manually as in the example below.

Instead I would like to specify something like "top-within" or "left/right- upper/lower" corner. As far as I know there is no predefined option but maybe someone already found a way to do it?

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
              dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
              len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
ggplot(df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=supp)) + 
geom_line(aes(linetype=supp)) + theme(legend.position = c(0.3, 0.8))
```

The example is taken from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#data.

All the best

Comment: These values `c(0.3, 0.8)` are percentages. Thus use  `c(0.1, 0.2)` for "bottom-left-within" or ` c(0.1, 0.8)` for "top-left-within".

Comment: yes, but do you know how to automatically find the position where legends are still within plot boundaries? when I manually specify them my legends often exceed plot boundaries.

Comment: I typically find that using the same numbers for `legend.justification = c(x, y)` along with `legend.position = c(x, y)` does a good job.